# Symfony 5 - Display id and slug in category url and find it by id when slug is updated

Tags: symfony, routes, seo

My category url contains both id and slug like https://myapp.com/category/56-category-name (id field = 56 and slug field = category-name in the DB), when updating category name the slug field in DB is updated but the id still the same.
I would like to display my category whatever the slug provided that the id is correct and of course display the correct url. In this case SEO still correct i think.

Here my show method :

```
/**
 * @Route("/category/{id}-{slug}", name="category_show", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 */
public function show(CategoryRepository $categoryRepository, $slug, $id): Response
{

    $category = $categoryRepository->find($id);
    if($category->getSlug() !== $slug) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('category_show', [
            'id' => $id,
            'slug' => $category->getSlug()
        ]);
    }
    return $this->render('category/show.html.twig', [
        'category' => $category
    ]);
}
```

It works if the given id exists in DB, othewise i got an error **Call to a member function getSlug() on null**. I can throw a NotFoundException, but i think this method use many times queries.

So please help me doing these properly with more flexibility and performance.
In case I would like to display the category in the post url as well like https://myapp.com/56-category-name/23-post-title how to go about it ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, if I understand your problem maybe try to create a custom method in your repository like "findByIdOrSlug", what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what i found good for my app :

in my CategoryController.php i create, the show method :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}-{slug}", name="category_show", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 */
public function show(CategoryRepository $categoryRepository, $slug = null, $id): Response
{

    $category = $categoryRepository->find($id);
    
    if (!$category) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    if($category->getSlug() !== $slug) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('category_show', [
            'id' => $id,
            'slug' => $category->getSlug()
        ]);
    }
    return $this->render('category/show.html.twig', [
        'category' => $category
    ]);
}
```

in my index template to display the category_show link :

```
<a href="{{ path('category_show', {'slug': category.slug, 'id': category.id}) }}">show</a>
```

in my ArticleController.php i create, the show method :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{category}/{id}-{slug}", name="article_show", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 */
public function show(ArticleRepository $articleRepository, $slug = null, $id, $category = null): Response
{
    $article = $articleRepository->find($id);
    
    if (!$article) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
    
    $cat = $article->getCategory()->getId() . '-' . $article->getCategory()->getSlug();

    if($article->getSlug() !== $slug || $cat !== $category) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', [
            'id' => $id,
            'slug' => $article->getSlug(),
            'category' => $cat
        ]);
    }
    return $this->render('article/show.html.twig', [
        'article' => $article,
    ]);
}
```

in my index template to display the article_show link :

```
<a href="{{ path('article_show', {'category': article.category.id ~ '-' ~ article.category.slug, 'slug': article.slug, 'id': article.id}) }}">show</a>
```

For me that solves my problem. But still, if we can improve the process, I'm a buyer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [findOneBy()](https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/3.3/doctrine.html) and check if the result is `null`

```
/**
 * @Route("/category/{id}-{slug}", name="category_show", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @Route("/{id}-{slug}/{idArticle}-{postSlug}", name="article_show", requirements={"idArticle"="\d+"})
 */
public function show(CategoryRepository $categoryRepository, $slug, $id, $idArticle = false, $postSlug = false ): Response
{

    $category = $categoryRepository->findOneBy(['id'=>$id]);
    if(is_null($category)){
      throw new NotFoundHttpException(); //404, nothing found
    }else{
      //Category found.
      if($idArticle){ //  https://myapp.com/56-category-name/23-post-title
         //Article route, put your logic here 
      }else{ //https://myapp.com/category/56-category-name 
        // Category route, logic here
        if($category->getSlug() !== $slug) {
           return $this->redirectToRoute('category_show', [
              'id' => $id,
              'slug' => $category->getSlug()
           ]);
        }
        return $this->render('category/show.html.twig', [
          'category' => $category
        ]);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. But in case I would like to display the category in the post url as well like https://myapp.com/56-category-name/23-post-title how to go about it ??

Comment: @bahahmadou94 check the code now. I've added a second route.

Comment: Thanks you for your help 